# How to add class attribute in angular 2 component typescript file?

Tags: angular

How to add class attribute in angular 2 component typescript file ?

Below is my footer component code, i want to add **footer** class to it.

**footer.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Footer }    from './footer';
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'footer',
  templateUrl: 'footer.component.html'
})
export class FooterComponent {
constructor() {
    this.title = 'Footer Content';
    this.css_class = 'navbar-fixed-bottom';
  }
}
```

**footer.ts**

```
export class Footer {
  constructor(
    public title: string
  ) {  }
}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: share your template from footer.component.html

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `host` metadata property of the Component decorator. 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Component-decorator.html

Your Component decorator should look like this:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'footer',
  templateUrl: 'footer.component.html',
  host: {'class': 'my-footer'}
})
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do add CSS class to your HTML.

first is that

```
<div class='{{css_class}}'>...</div>
```

and second is you can add CSS class based on some conditions/flag, CSS class will be added to dom when a condition is true.

```
export class FooterComponent {
 let addCssClass : boolean = true;

 constructor() {
    this.title = 'Footer Content';
    this.css_class = 'navbar-fixed-bottom';
  }
}
```

in you HTML `<div [class.navbar-fixed-bottom]="addCssClass">...</div>` when ever **addCssClass** is true **navbar-fixed-bottom** will added to the div.

Answer (score 2):

On Angular v7+ it is recommended to use `HostBinding` to achieve this.

```
import { HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {

  @HostBinding('class') class = 'my-footer';
  constructor(){};
  ...
}
```

From [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-06-03)

Answer (score 1):

First make your variable `css_class` a public property of your component

Then, in your template footer.component.html, just interpolate your variable `css_class` as follow:

```
<div class='{{css_class}}'>test</div>
```

This is just an example the important part is the `class` attribute and its value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign `Footer` type to variable of your component :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Footer }    from './footer';
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'footer',
  templateUrl: 'footer.component.html'
})
export class FooterComponent {

  public footerClass: Footer;

  constructor() {
    this.footerClass = new Footer('Footer Content');
  }
}
```